# Problem with Test Class If/Else string is null

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

I have the following class that I need to cover. It takes the search value from the VF Page and creates a list based on the entered value.

```
public with sharing class ServiceConsoleFastLinksController {
    
    public List<Service_Console_Fast_Links__c> allLinks;
    public string searchField{get; set;}
    
    public ServiceConsoleFastLinksController () {

        Map<String,Service_Console_Fast_Links__c> flMap = Service_Console_Fast_Links__c.getAll();
        allLinks = flMap.values();
        allLinks.sort();   // will sort the custom setting on the Name field    
        
    }
    

    public List<Service_Console_Fast_Links__c> getFastLinks () {

        List<Service_Console_Fast_Links__c> filteredLinks = new List<Service_Console_Fast_Links__c>();
        
        for (Service_Console_Fast_Links__c fl : allLinks){
            if (this.searchField == null)
                filteredLinks.add(fl);
            else if(fl.name.startsWithIgnoreCase(this.searchField))
                    filteredLinks.add(fl);
        }
        
        return filteredLinks;
    }   
    
    public pageReference updateList() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have it covered at 73% with the following:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class ServiceConsoleFastLinksControllerTest {
    

    
    public static testMethod void testServiceConsoleFastLinksController () {

        List<Service_Console_Fast_Links__c> testLinks;

        ServiceConsoleFastLinksController ctrl = new ServiceConsoleFastLinksController();
        Map<String,Service_Console_Fast_Links__c> flMap = Service_Console_Fast_Links__c.getAll();
        testlinks = flmap.values();
        testLinks.sort();
        
        system.assertEquals(ctrl.getFastLinks(), testLinks, 'The links are not the same');
        
        system.assertEquals(ctrl.updateList(), null, 'The list is returned null');
        ctrl.searchField = null;
        system.assertEquals(ctrl.getFastLinks(), testLinks, 'The links are not the same');
        
       }
}
```

But I can't seem to cover the if/else clause - setting the value of searchfield to null.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your if statements to produce just one, and this should get you to 100%:

```
for (Service_Console_Fast_Links__c fl : allLinks){
  if (this.searchField == null || fl.name.startsWithIgnoreCase(this.searchField)) {
    filteredLinks.add(fl);
  }
}
```

The `||` operator will stop on the lefthand-side of the operator, avoiding the null pointer exception you'd get otherwise.

Regardless, you'll want to also set `searchField` to a non-null value to try and get some matches.

Finally, note that `Service_Console_Fast_Links__c` appears to be a Custom Setting, so you'll need to make sure that you insert some values, because of the [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that. It is a Custom Setting, I was thinking it was universal throughout or orgs however I probably should create some data for it.

Comment: @JonathanCrow Unless you use `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`, custom settings are isolated from production data, just like normal records. It's one of those things you should definitely create in your unit test.

Comment: So I added the setting and modified the code as you suggest and 100%. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce tends to initialize any fields with a get/set so they are never actually null. I would change the check to be an isblank check

```
if (String.IsBlank(this.searchField) {
}
```

Comment: You're usually spot on, but not in this case. They just never tried the other branch.

Comment: Also realized they probably didn't insert any test records (custom settings).